# Under what case is the iOS system push notification pop up is called?

Tags: ios, push-notification, app-store, push

I have submitted an app to the iOS app store where the push notifications are available but were not enabled, thus their status is 'configurable' (yellow light).

Will this still call the system message to allow/block push?

Answer (score 0):

No, if push notifications are not enabled, you won't see that popup.

The user can only choose to allow push notifications if the app was built with a provisioning profile that has push entitlement, which requires to create a push certificate for the app ID.